# Jackson can't deserialize JSON it serializes with enableDefaultTyping()

Tags: java, jackson

Using Jackson 2.9.5, I am serializing an object to JSON and deserializing it back to a Java object. Upon deserializing the JSON, Jackson throws this exception:

```
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException: Cannot deserialize instance of 'com.xxx.models.Header' out of START_ARRAY token
     at [Source: (String)"{
      "header" : [ "com.xxx.models.Header", {
        "sourceAddress" : 0,
        "destinationAddress" : 1, ...
```

That's semi-understandable because the deserialized JSON looks like this:

```
{
  "header" : [ "com.xxx.models.Header", {
    "sourceAddress" : 0,
    "destinationAddress" : 1
]}
```

Jackson adds the array syntax when `mapper.enableDefaultTyping()`, `mapper.enableDefaultTyping(ObjectMapper.DefaultTyping.OBJECT_AND_NON_CONCRETE)`, or `mapper.enableDefaultTyping(ObjectMapper.DefaultTyping.NON_CONCRETE_AND_ARRAYS)` is used and `writeValueAsString()` is called.

But calling `readValue()` on the same object mapper to deserialize the same JSON it *just* generated throws the above exception. Why? **What am I doing wrong?**

I should note that if I strip out the added `[ "com.xxx.models.Header",` bit (and its corresponding array terminator) the JSON is parsed as expected and the deserialized object is fully populated.

It seems like this is specifically related to polymorphism, so here are the object definitions. A `SerialMessage` contains an `IHeader` and `IPayload`. A `Header` extends an `AbstractHeader` which implements `IHeader` and is what I'm serializing and can't deserialize.

```
public class SerialMessage {

    private IHeader header;
    private IPayload payload;

    public SerialMessage() {};
    public SerialMessage(IHeader header) {
        this.header = header;
    }

    public SerialMessage(IHeader header, IPayload payload) {
        this(header);
        this.payload = payload;
    };

    public IHeader getHeader() {
        return header;
    }
    public void setHeader(Header header) {
        this.header = header;
    }
    public IPayload getPayload() {
        return payload;
    }
    public void setPayload(IPayload payload) {
        this.payload = payload;
    }
}
```

.

```
public class AbstractHeader implements IHeader {

    protected short sourceAddress;
    protected short destinationAddress;

    public short getSourceAddress() {
        return sourceAddress;
    }

    public void setSourceAddress(short sourceAddress) {
        this.sourceAddress = sourceAddress;
    }

    public short getDestinationAddress() {
        return destinationAddress;
    }

    public void setDestinationAddress(short destinationAddress) {
        this.destinationAddress = destinationAddress;
    }
}
```

.

```
public class Header extends AbstractHeader {
}
```

Comment: Your json is malformed it should be [{"key":"value"}]

Comment: @GauravSrivastav I think only string values are to be quoted in JSON. In my case the values are numbers.

Comment: What about   "header" : [ "com.xxx.models.Header", {...

Comment: @GauravSrivastav Jackson adds the array syntax when mapper.enableDefaultTyping() is used. It's supposed to allow Jackson to identify which concrete class type the JSON should be deserialized to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a consistent problem with deserializing Jackson-serialized objects with `enableDefaultTyping()`, `mapper.enableDefaultTyping(ObjectMapper.DefaultTyping.OBJECT_AND_NON_CONCRETE)`, or `mapper.enableDefaultTyping(ObjectMapper.DefaultTyping.NON_CONCRETE_AND_ARRAYS)`.

The root cause seems to be that Jackson simply doesn't understand its own wrapper syntax generated from these options. After much experimentation, Jackson was only able to deserialize the object hierarchy (from the question) it had serialized **if the objects were annotated with @JsonType.**

In the case shown in the question, the interface `IHeader` can be annotated as:

```
@JsonTypeInfo(use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.CLASS, include = JsonTypeInfo.As.PROPERTY)
public interface IHeader {
...
}
```

which produces the JSON

```
{
  "header" : {
    "@class" : "com.xxx.models.Header",
    "sourceAddress" : 0,
    "destinationAddress" : 1
}
```

instead of wrapping each object with an array syntax to indicate its implementation type.

I was not able to find a way to tell `ObjectMapper` to use the equivalent of JsonTypeInfo.As.PROPERTY. Annotating every interface with `@JsonType` is not ideal, but does provide a work-around the original problem.

See Jackson's documentation for `@JsonType` at https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-docs/wiki/JacksonPolymorphicDeserialization#12-per-class-annotations .

Answer (score 0):

```
    public IHeader getHeader() {
        return header;
    }
    public void setHeader(Header header) {
        this.header = header;
    }
```

The cause of the problem is that the getter of `header` field return a `Interface` type of `IHeader`, but the setter takes a concrete type of `Header`. When JSON serializing, the type of `header` field decides by its getter, that is `IHeader`, and `IHeader` is a polymorphic type. When JSON deserializing, the type of `header` field decides by its setter's parameter type, that is `Header`, and `Header` is a concrete type. so at this point, Jackson throws a exception with this message.

"Can not deserialize instance of xxx out of START_ARRAY token"

More details you can refer to `com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanSerializerFactory#_constructWriter` and `com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializerFactory#addBeanProps`